# Drupal 7: Use selections made on previous pages to generate correct pager?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, pagination

I'm making a gallery using Page Manager and Panels in Drupal 7.

Every painting in the gallery is related to a painter, a time period and several themes.

When navigating in the gallery, the user has three different routes to reach a specific painting:

1. Through painters
2. Through time periods
3. Through themes

When on the page for a specific painting, I would like to make a pagination system, that shows the next and the previous painting, based on the route the user took to get to the specific painting.

So if you reach the page with a painting through painters, the next and previous buttons should show the next and previous paintings from that painter.

If you reach the page with a painting through time periods, the next and previous buttons should show the next and previous paintings from the specific time period.

And if you reach the page with a painting through themes, the next and precious buttons should show the next and previous paintings from that specific theme.

The paintings only have one url each: /painting/%node so I somehow need to know what route the user took to get to a specific painting in order to generate the correct previous and next buttons.

Anybody know a clever way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the gallery into the page via ajax/javascript after the page has loaded, this way you could use the javascript History object and send it to the view as an argument.